# C3.js Scatter plot - how to associate third data (additional value) as part of original column data for callbacks to set radius and display in tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot, c3.js

I'm using C3.js to display a scatter plot chart. I have server responded data as

`{"data":[{"point":"x":47.44244604316546762589928057553957,"y":192435.7032514613309352517985611511},"volume":278},"point":"x":48.02666666666666666666666666666667,"y":203699.56703125},"volume":300},"point":"x":47.34313725490196078431372549019608,"y":189978.6420419730392156862745098039},"volume":306},"point":"x":46.11003236245954692556634304207120,"y":200044.0157766990291262135922330097},"volume":309},"point":"x":47.81107491856677524429967426710098,"y":197468.1842935667752442996742671010},"volume":307}
]}`

With the above data, I generated C3ChartOptions data option as

```
"data": {
    "xs": {
      "y1": "x0"
    },
    "columns": [
      [
        "x0",
        47.442446043165,
        48.026666666667,
        47.343137254902,
        46.11003236246,
        47.811074918567
      ],
      [
        "y1",
        192435.70325146,
        203699.56703125,
        189978.64204197,
        200044.0157767,
        197468.18429357
      ]
    ],
    "type": "scatter",
    "axes": {
      "y1": "y"
    }
  }
```

and assigned weight data in a separate variable like 
`var volume= [278,300,306,309,307];`

For setting the radius of circle based on **volume** data, I did below

```
point: {
      r: function(d) {
        return volume[d.index] * 0.04;
      }
    }
```

To show **volume** data as part of tooltip, I did below

```
tooltip :{
  contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
  var text = "<table class='c3-tooltip'>";

text += "<tr class='c3-tooltip-name'><td class='name'><span style='background-color:#ff7f0e'></span>Age</td><td class='value'>" + d[0].x + "</td></tr>"

text += "<tr class='c3-tooltip-name'><td class='name'><span style='background-color:#ff7f0e'></span>"+d[0].name+"</td><td class='value'>" + d[0].value + "</td></tr>"

text += "<tr class='c3-tooltip-name'><td class='name'><span style='background-color:#ff7f0e'></span>Weight</td><td class='value'>" + volume[d[0].index] + "</td></tr>"

text += "</table>";

return text;
};
```

In both the above two cases, I'm getting incorrect **volume** data (wrong index) inside radius function and as well in tooltip.

What is wrong in the above strategy? If its not a proper way, How will I normally map third dataset to original column data for callbacks, so that I can retrieve it inside radius and tooltip function instead of having it separately and referencing it using incorrect index (**d.index**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addressed the issue by using the same process mentioned above by keeping **volume** data array separately and tried accessing it using index (**d.index**) inside my callbacks for setting radius and showing in tooltip.

In order to fix the incorrect index access issue, we need to set additional **option** for **data** like below

```
data: {
  xSort: false,
  .
  .
  . //other options
}
```

This will tell C3 not to sort the given data, so that you can access the additional data with the same index.

For reference, https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/547#issuecomment-56292971. Thanks @masayuki0812 for the solution. But anyway it should have been handled within library itself. Also there is no documentation yet for ***data.xSort*** option in http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-xSort

Comment: I am trying to do what you did with a a separate array for the Z values, but the index returned is always 0... See here: https://jsfiddle.net/robsilva/q9wfpyze/